# Re-using same button for multiple rows in table layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button

I have a Table layout that contains 3 rows with each row having a character name, current attributes and a button for re-rolling character attributes.

Like this:

```
Malarku   s:10 i:15 c:5  [Re-Roll]
Zipak     s:17 i:3 c:22  [Re-Roll]
Ambra     s:6 i:24 c:7   [Re-Roll]
```

My problem is the button, because it has an id attached to it like this:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/ButtonRollStats"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/button_rollStats"
    android:tag="@string/char1_name" />
```

And in my main activity code file, I have this:

```
Button rollStats = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ButtonRollStats);
rollStats.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        AddStatsView(view);
    }
});

public void AddStatsView(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayStatsView.class);
    String tag = view.getTag().toString();
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_NAME, tag);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

So I can't use the same button ID in each table row but I need the ID to find it and I don't want to have to use a different ID and method for each button when they all do the same thing(rolling stats).

How do I get around this issue?

Comment: You have to do 1 of those two things. You can find all of them by 3 different `ids` and then simply make all of their on click listeners the same. Easy way would be make your class implement the `View.OnClickListener` and then set all listeners to `this`.

Comment: @Vucko thanks...my class is already using View.OnClickListener. But I still need to get the ID of the button. How would using 'this' work?  Thanks!

Comment: When your class implements the interface, you can set it to be the parameter of the `rollStats.setOnClickListener(this)` like so. Just do this for all buttons, and it's not much code repetition. It is merely a different approach.

Comment: I can not understand the question, can u elaborate please @SkyeBoniwell

Comment: @Vucko but rollStats is the Button object I get with findViewById...

Comment: I know. So find all 3 buttons by their **unique** ids and then set the listeners like for that one I showed.

Comment: Oh I see.  Thanks!